# AndroidSlidingUpPanel: Disable main content interaction when sliding up

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-sliding

I am using AndroidSlidingPanel library implemented a sliding up panel feature similar as below:

[image]

The main content is a `GoogleMap` instance.

Currently, when sliding up the panel, the map is still interactive with finger gestures. I would like to disable map interaction when panel sliding up. How to achieve this?

I tried mySlidingPanel.setTouchEnable(false) but it doesn't fit my need. I can't find from the documentation how to do it either.

Comment: You can use slide panel listener to see in which state the panel is. When the panel is still sliding, you can just set touch to enable on the map to be false and once the panel has settled to the desired state you can enable the map.

Comment: @AnkushSharma, yes, but the question is how to set enable to false for only the map part when panel is slided up?

Comment: if its a map fragment you can assign clickable=false to it. Would it be possible for you to show your complete layout where you are adding sliding panel